# Asp.Net Validation Control With Javascript

Tags: asp.net

When I Was Trying To `causesvalidation=false` for my server side validation control like requiredfieldvalidation.

i want manually `causesvalidation=false` using javascript but i m not done . is there any solution..

Answer (score 2):

I am but late to reply to this question but it will be helpful to others

To apply a `causesvalidation` attribute to a button via jQuery is very simple. All you have to do is assign class to your button for example assign a cancel class to it like below

```
<a href="URL URL" class="cancel" >Home</a>
```

within document.ready function of jQuery

```
 //get your button by class
 var $cancelButton = $(".cancel");

//assign the attribute
$cancelButton.attr("CausesValidation", "False");
```

by doing this you can assign this validation attribute to any button just assign their class and assign attribute via jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try(Untested):

```
document.getElementById("<%= YourControl.ClientID  %>").setAttribute("causesvalidation", "false");
```